# Why is data not transmitted to the controller?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I have next form:

```
<form asp-controller="Chat" asp-action="AddFile" method="post"  asp-route-chatId="@Model.ChatId" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    <textarea id="messageInput" class="textInput" style="width: 80vh" name="messageInput"></textarea>
                    <div>
                        <input type="submit" id="sendButton" value="Send Message" />
                        <input type="file" class="inputfile " id="File" name="File" value="File"/>
                        <label for="File">Choose a file</label>
                    </div>
                </form>
```

ViewModel

```
public class ChatFileViewModel
{
    public long ChatId { get; set; }
    public string messageInput { get; set; }
    public IFormFile File { get; set; }
}
```

and post method:

```
[HttpPost]
    public void AddFile([FromBody] ChatFileViewModel chatFile)
    { ... }
```

The issue is - every time i press submit it transfers ChatId correctly, while messageInput and File are null. I have no idea what it is, because i have exactly the same construction working correctly in the other part of my app.

Answer (score 0):

You should remove the [FromBody] attribute, since your request data is in the form. [FromBody] is usually used to deal with data in the request body like JSON and XML

```
[HttpPost]
public void AddFile(ChatFileViewModel chatFile)
{ ... }
```

For more details, you can refer to [Model binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding?view=aspnetcore-3.1#frombody-attribute).

Answer (score 0):

Using `[FromBody]` To force Web API to read a `simple type` from the request body, but your object is complex contain string and int can not treat as simple type.

Remove FormBody, I reproduce and it worked

[image]

More about FormBody at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api

Comment: This doesn't seem to work. File and message are still null.

Comment: only copy your code and remove FormBody, it worked in my machine

Comment: Perhaps the problem is that the model of the page is not the model i want to send to controller? I mean the model of my page is ChatViewModel while the data i am sending is ChatFileView model.

Answer (score 0):

if you need of want to specify binding then you can use `[FromForm]` because you correctly setup for into `multipart/form-data` but it depends on your other actions

```
 public IActionResult AddFile([FromForm]ChatFileViewModel model)
```

if you use asp- tag helpers you can use them for controls as well

```
<form asp-controller="Home" asp-action="AddFile" method="post"  asp-route-chatId="@Model.ChatId" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <textarea asp-for="messageInput" class="textInput" style="width: 80vh" name="messageInput"></textarea>
    <div>
        <input type="submit" id="sendButton" value="Send Message" />
        <input type="file" class="inputfile " asp-for="File" />
        <label asp-for="File">Choose a file</label>
    </div>
</form>
```